# Consulta em SQL para Linq mvc4 c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Não sou muito familiarizado com Linq e estou com dificuldade em transformar essa consulta SQL em linq, alguém pode me ajudar.

Faço o `join` de 6 tabelas (não fui eu quem fiz a base de dados. Tenho que trabalhar com ela), o que estou agarrado é no `group by` e no `having`

```
select processosProduto.PRODUTO,SUM(pedidosVenda1.QUANT) as vendidos ,processosProduto.QUANT as estoque, processoFinanceiro.CODIGO, processoFinanceiro.ProdutosContidos
from processoFinanceiro 
join processosProduto on processoFinanceiro.CODIGO = processosProduto.CODIGO
join OrdemDeCompra on processosProduto.PRODUTO = OrdemDeCompra.Codigo
join produtos on OrdemDeCompra.PARALELO = produtos.CODIGO
join pedidosVenda1 on produtos.CODIGO = pedidosVenda1.PRODUTO
join pedidosVenda on pedidosVenda1.CODIGO = pedidosVenda.CODIGO
where pedidosVenda.NPedido = processoFinanceiro.NPedidoFornecedor 
group by processosProduto.PRODUTO,processosProduto.QUANT,  processoFinanceiro.CODIGO, processoFinanceiro.ProdutosContidos
having SUM(pedidosVenda1.QUANT) < processosProduto.QUANT*120/100
```

**EDITADO**

Aqui está o que eu consegui fazer até agora

```
var listaDb = (from pf in db.processoFinanceiro
                           join pp in db.processosProduto on pf.CODIGO equals pp.CODIGO
                           join oc in db.OrdemDeCompras on pp.PRODUTO equals oc.PARALELO
                           join pr in db.produtos on oc.PARALELO equals pr.CODIGO
                           join pv1 in db.pedidosVenda1 on pr.CODIGO equals pv1.PRODUTO
                           join pv in db.pedidosVenda on pv1.CODIGO equals pv.CODIGO
                           where pv.NPedido == pf.NPedidoFornecedor
```

mas não estou conseguindo desenvolver mais do que esse ponto, como disse  o que estou agarrado é no `group by` e no `having`

Comment: Poste seu modelo. e o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Editei a publicação com as informações solicitadas. Sei que falta fechar o parênteses, e que falta mais código, como o select, mas preciso desenvolver o having e group by antes de prosseguir ( eu acho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem o modelo para fazer um teste ficar um pouco difícil, mas veja como funcionaria o `group by` e o `having` no linq.

Praticamente o `having` se torna um `where` depois do `group by`.

```
var listaDb = (from pf in db.processoFinanceiro
               join pp in db.processosProduto on pf.CODIGO equals pp.CODIGO
               join oc in db.OrdemDeCompras on pp.PRODUTO equals oc.PARALELO
               join pr in db.produtos on oc.PARALELO equals pr.CODIGO
               join pv1 in db.pedidosVenda1 on pr.CODIGO equals pv1.PRODUTO
               join pv in db.pedidosVenda on pv1.CODIGO equals pv.CODIGO
               where pv.NPedido == pf.NPedidoFornecedor
               group pv by new { pp.PRODUTO, pf.CODIGO, pf.ProdutosContidos } into g
               where g.Sum(pp => pp.QUANT) < (g.Sum(pp => pp.QUANT) *120/100)
               select new 
               { 
                    PRODUTO = g.Key.PRODUTO, 
                    CODIGO = g.Key.CODIGO, 
                    ProdutosContidos = g.Key.ProdutosContidos,
                    QUANT = g.Sum(pp => pp.QUANT) 
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

fiz aqui Por cima deve ser algo como isto:

```
(from pf in processoFinanceiro
            join pp in processosProduto on pf.CODIGO equals pp.CODIGO
            join oc in OrdemDeCompras on pp.PRODUTO equals oc.PARALELO
            join pr in produtos on oc.PARALELO equals pr.CODIGO
            join pv1 in pedidosVenda1 on pr.CODIGO equals pv1.PRODUTO
            join pv in pedidosVenda on pv1.CODIGO equals pv.CODIGO
            group new {pp.PRODUTO, pp.QUANT, pvQUANT = pv1.QUANT, pf.CODIGO, pf.ProdutosContidos}
            by new {pp.PRODUTO, pp.QUANT, pf.CODIGO, pf.ProdutosContidos}
            into grp               
            select new
            {
                grp.Key.PRODUTO,
                vendidos = grp.Sum(b=>b.pvQUANT),
                estoque = grp.Key.QUANT,
                grp.Key.CODIGO,
                grp.Key.ProdutosContidos
            });
```

no `Group new {....}` você coloca as propriedades que vai utilizar para retornar e no `by new {...}` você coloca as propriedades que você quer agrupar

ex: se você quer fazer o SUM, não pode colocar esta propriedade no by pois só irá agrupar as propriedades que forem iguais.

[REFERENCIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250991/how-to-get-a-sum-in-linq)

Comment: Acho que sua consulta esta bem próximo do que ele precisar, só faltou o filtro do having.

Comment: Muito obrigado @MarconcilioSouza! através desse código consegui realizar a busca, estava faltando um where ' where pv.NPedido == pf.NPedidoFornecedor' e o having eu consigo fazer em cima do resultado da pesquisa

Comment: tenho que dar um groupby codigo e selecionar codigo e ProdutosContidos , mas obtenho um erro de tentar converter um Iqueriable<AnonimousType#4> para um Iqueriable<AnonimousType#2> sabe o que pode ser isso?
 query = (from c in query
                     where c.estoque > c.vendidos
                     group new { c.CODIGO, c.ProdutosContidos }
                     by new { c.CODIGO} 
                     into gr
                     select new
                     { gr.Key.CODIGO,
                       gr.Key.ProdutosContidos
                     });